# Pen-like behaviour when setting model matrix for freetype in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics

So here's the thing. I'm trying to create a Text class using Freetype, which inherits from a Model class, which in turn contains stuff like setting VAO, VBOs, programs, textures, position, rotation and scaling. Here's the code for Model.cpp:

```
// Model.cpp
#include "Model.h"

using namespace OpenGL::Rendering;

Model::Model() {
    model_matrix = glm::mat4(1.0f);
    position = glm::vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    scale = glm::vec3(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    rotation = glm::vec3(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    rotation_angle = 0.0;
}

Model::~Model() { destroy(); }

void Model::draw() {}

void Model::set_program(GLuint program) { this->program = program; }

GLuint Model::get_vao() const { return vao; }

const std::vector<GLuint>& Model::get_vbos() const { return vbos; }

GLuint Model::get_texture(std::string texture_name) const {
    if (textures.size() > 0) {
        return textures.at(texture_name);
    } else {
        Log()->critical("No textures to get. Requested {}", texture_name);
        return 0;
    }
}

GLuint Model::get_texture() const {
    if (textures.size() > 0) {
        return textures.begin()->second;
    } else {
        Log()->critical("No textures to get.");
        return 0;
    }
}

void Model::set_texture(std::string texture_name, GLuint texture) {
    if (texture == 0) {
        Log()->critical("Texture {} is empty.", texture_name);
        return;
    } else {
        textures[texture_name] = texture;
    }
}

void Model::destroy() {
    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &vao);
    glDeleteBuffers(vbos.size(), &vbos[0]);
    vbos.clear();

    if (textures.size() > 0) {
        for (auto& t : textures) {
            glDeleteTextures(1, &t.second);
        }

        textures.clear();
    }
}

const glm::vec3& Model::get_position() const { return position; }

void Model::set_position(float pos_x, float pos_y, float pos_z) {
    position = glm::vec3(pos_x, pos_y, pos_z);
    update_model_matrix();
}

void Model::set_rotation(float angle_deg, float x, float y, float z) {
    rotation_angle = angle_deg * M_PI / 180.0;
    rotation = glm::vec3(x, y, z);
    update_model_matrix();
}

void Model::set_scale(float sca_x, float sca_y, float sca_z) {
    scale = glm::vec3(sca_x, sca_y, sca_z);
    update_model_matrix();
}

void Model::update_model_matrix() {
    model_matrix = glm::mat4(1.0f);
    auto pos = glm::vec3(this->position.x, -this->position.y, this->position.z);
    glm::mat4 translate_mat = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0f), pos);
    glm::mat4 rotate_mat = glm::mat4(1.0f);
    if (this->rotation.x != 0.0 || this->rotation.y != 0.0 || this->rotation.z != 0.0) {
        rotate_mat = glm::rotate(glm::mat4(1.0f), this->rotation_angle, this->rotation);
    } else {
        rotate_mat =
            glm::rotate(glm::mat4(1.0f), 0.0f, glm::vec3(1.0, 0.0, 0.0));
    }

    glm::mat4 scale_mat = glm::scale(glm::mat4(1.0f), this->scale);

    this->model_matrix = translate_mat * rotate_mat * scale_mat;
    glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(this->program, "model_matrix"), 1,
                       false, &this->model_matrix[0][0]);
}
```

Then I have my Text class, which uses Freetype to load fonts and stuff. I know it's not optimised really, so look past that. Note that for Freetype, I'm using GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW, instead of GL_STATIC_DRAW

```
// Text.cpp
#include "Text.h"

using namespace OpenGL::Rendering::Models;

Text::Text(const std::string& text, OpenGL::Container::Position position,
           int font_size, OpenGL::Container::Color color) {
    m_font_size = font_size;
    m_scale = 1.0;
    m_text = text;
    float angle = 0;
    this->color.r = color.r;
    this->color.g = color.g;
    this->color.b = color.b;
    this->color.a = color.a;

    matrix.xx = (FT_Fixed)(cos(angle) * 0x10000L);
    matrix.xy = (FT_Fixed)(-sin(angle) * 0x10000L);
    matrix.yx = (FT_Fixed)(sin(angle) * 0x10000L);
    matrix.yy = (FT_Fixed)(cos(angle) * 0x10000L);

    this->position.x = position.x;
    this->position.y = position.y;
    this->position.z = position.z;

    if (FT_Init_FreeType(&font)) {
        Log()->critical("Could not initalize Freetype library for fonts.");
    }

    if (FT_New_Face(font, "/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ubuntu/Ubuntu-R.ttf", 0,
                    &face)) {
        Log()->critical("Could not load font. File is missing maybe?");
    }

    FT_Set_Char_Size(face, 0, m_font_size * 64, 300, 300);
    FT_Set_Pixel_Sizes(face, 0, m_font_size);
    if (FT_Load_Char(face, 'X', FT_LOAD_RENDER)) {
        Log()->critical(
            "Could not load a test glyph. The font is corrupted maybe?");
    }

    for (GLubyte c = 0; c < 128; ++c) {
        FT_Set_Transform(face, &matrix, 0);
        if (FT_Load_Char(face, c, FT_LOAD_RENDER)) {
            Log()->critical("Could not load glyph \"{}\"", c);
            continue;
        }

        GLuint texture;
        glGenTextures(1, &texture);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RED, face->glyph->bitmap.width,
                     face->glyph->bitmap.rows, 0, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
                     face->glyph->bitmap.buffer);

        glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);

        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

        Character character = {
            texture,
            glm::ivec2(face->glyph->bitmap.width, face->glyph->bitmap.rows),
            glm::ivec2(face->glyph->bitmap_left, face->glyph->bitmap_top),
            face->glyph->advance.x};

        characters.insert(std::pair<GLchar, Character>(c, character));
    }

    FT_Done_Face(face);
    FT_Done_FreeType(font);
}

void Text::create() {
    GLuint vao;
    GLuint vbo;

    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
    glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);

    glBindVertexArray(vao);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLfloat) * 6 * 4, NULL,
                 GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 4 * sizeof(GLfloat),
                          (void*)0);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);

    this->vao = vao;
    this->vbos.push_back(vbo);
    this->set_program(OpenGL::Managers::ShaderManager::get_program("text"));
    // this->set_position(position.x, position.y, position.z);
    Log()->warn("Pos {0}, {1}, {2}", position.x, position.y, position.z);
}

void Text::draw() {
    GLfloat temp_x = 0;
    GLfloat temp_y = 0;
    glUseProgram(this->program);
    glUniform4f(glGetUniformLocation(this->program, "text_color"), color.r,
                color.g, color.b, color.a);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindVertexArray(this->vao);

    std::string::const_iterator c;
    for (c = m_text.begin(); c != m_text.end(); c++) {
        Character ch = characters[*c];

        GLfloat xpos = temp_x + ch.bearing.x * m_scale;
        GLfloat ypos = temp_y - (ch.size.y - ch.bearing.y) * m_scale;

        GLfloat w = ch.size.x * m_scale;
        GLfloat h = ch.size.y * m_scale;

        GLfloat vertices[6][4] = {
            {xpos, ypos + h, 0.0, 0.0}, /**/
            {xpos, ypos, 0.0, 1.0},     /**/
            {xpos + w, ypos, 1.0, 1.0}, /**/

            {xpos, ypos + h, 0.0, 0.0},    /**/
            {xpos + w, ypos, 1.0, 1.0},    /**/
            {xpos + w, ypos + h, 1.0, 0.0} /**/
        };

        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, ch.texture_id);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this->vbos[0]);
        glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(vertices), vertices);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
        temp_x += (ch.advance >> 6) * m_scale;
    }
    glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(this->program, "model_matrix"), 1,
                       false, &model_matrix[0][0]);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
}

void Text::set_text(const std::string& a_text) {
    if (!a_text.empty()) {
        m_text = a_text;
    } else {
        Log()->info("Cannot set the text. Input seems to be empty.");
    }
}

std::string Text::get_text() { return m_text; }

void Text::set_color(const Container::Color a_color) {
    color.r = a_color.r;
    color.g = a_color.g;
    color.b = a_color.b;
    color.a = a_color.a;
}
```

So the problem is, drawing a text behaves like a pen. So when I try to set the position of text1 object, text2 object moves. text2 affects text3 and so on.

```
// main.cpp
// This one moves to 200, 100 as defined in text3
auto text1 = new OpenGL::Rendering::Models::Text(
    "Text1", Container::Position(pos_x - 5, pos_y - radius, 0), 18,
    Container::Color::YELLOW);
text1->create();
text1->set_scale(3, 3, 3);
text1->set_position(500, 500, 0);
// This line actually affects text1, as expected
text1->set_text("Blah");

// This one scales to 3 times bigger, as stated in the previous object
auto text2 = new OpenGL::Rendering::Models::Text(
    "Text2", Container::Position(pos_x - radius - 10, pos_y + radius/1.5, 0), 18,
    Container::Color::YELLOW);
text2->create();
text2->set_rotation(25, 0, 0, 1);

// And this one gets rotated 
auto text3 = new OpenGL::Rendering::Models::Text(
    "Text3", Container::Position(0, 0, 0), 125,
    Container::Color::YELLOW);
text3->create();
text3->set_position(200, 100, 0);
```

Here's how it looks like:
[image: Screenshot of the issue]

Can somebody please explain this weird behaviour? The problem is, all other 2D shapes work just fine with my functions, except this Text class, which kinda affects the next object. Thank you very much in advance. If you need more information to diagnose the problem, I'll add it right away.

Comment: Why do you set the `model_matrix` after drawing the text in `Text::draw()`? The matrix should be set to the current program object before drawing the text, shouldn't it?

Comment: @Rabbid76 It doesn't really matter. Shaders can be updated at runtime anytime I guess. I set the program for the current object, then update the values. `Text::draw()` gets called in my main loop to update the context on each frame.

Comment: No, the program uses the values of the uniform variables as stated at the point of the draw call (`glDrawArrays`)

Comment: @Rabbid76 Thank you so much! That actually fixed the issue. How dumb of me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments by @Rabbid76, moving the below line to the beginning of `Text::draw()` fixed the problem:

```
glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(this->program, "model_matrix"), 1,
                   false, &model_matrix[0][0]);
```